# STM32 BLE profiles - multiple sensors active ST BLE Sensor App

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, communication, bluetooth-low-energy, android

I have done the [MOOC](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/support/learning/stm32-education/stm32-moocs/STM32WB_workshop_MOOC.html) for the stm32wb55 BLE profiles and now I am trying to introduce more BLE characteristics.
I managed to make the sensors work and to transmit them to the ST BLE Sensor app. However I can only have one screen active at a time. So for instance I can either have the temperature or humidity transmitted at a time, but not both at the same time.
I have created a custom template for both of them, and as I said separately they work fine, however I can't figure out how to have both of them at the same time on my ST BLE Sensor app.
Each template has its own UUID(in template_stm.c), specific to temperature and humidity, however I don't really understand this portion of the code from app_ble.c:

```
    /**
 * Advertising Data
 */
#if (P2P_SERVER1 != 0)
static const char local_name[] = { AD_TYPE_COMPLETE_LOCAL_NAME ,'T','R','Y','P','I'};
uint8_t manuf_data[14] = {
    sizeof(manuf_data)-1, AD_TYPE_MANUFACTURER_SPECIFIC_DATA, 
    0x01/*SKD version */,
    CFG_DEV_ID_P2P_SERVER1 /* STM32WB - P2P Server 1*/,
    0x00 /* GROUP A Feature  */,
    0x04 /* GROUP A Feature */, //0x00040000
    0x00 /* GROUP B Feature */,
    0x00 /* GROUP B Feature */,
    0x00, /* BLE MAC start -MSB */
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00, /* BLE MAC stop */
};
#endif
```

My transmission works only when I change the mask to 0x00040000 for temperature (the temperature screen in the app and the transmission work fine) or when I change it to 0x00080000 for humidity. How would I manage to have both of them at the same time? 
I read the documents associated in their entirety and also I checked the example apps, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Also as a separate issue, when I try to send the data to the pressure UUID, although the code is exactly the same to the other 2 examples, on the app it shows me "Not available".

Does anyone know how to solve these 2 issues?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello. Does anyone have any idea for this? I still haven't figured it out...

Comment: I share the same problem of the guy above, i can transmit more than one "enviromental sensor" per time but i can't see them on my smartphone. I used to modify feature mask bit according to table of BlueST protocol. If i need humidity and temperature i wrote 0x0C.
Anyone have suggest to solve these issues? I'm in trouble and need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bitmask so set each bit to identify what characteristics/features you want to export from the board:

0x000C0000 sets bit18 (Temperature) and bit19 (Humidity)

So:

```
 /**
 * Advertising Data
 */
#if (P2P_SERVER1 != 0)
static const char local_name[] = { AD_TYPE_COMPLETE_LOCAL_NAME ,'T','R','Y','P','I'};
uint8_t manuf_data[14] = {
    sizeof(manuf_data)-1, AD_TYPE_MANUFACTURER_SPECIFIC_DATA, 
    0x01/*SKD version */,
    CFG_DEV_ID_P2P_SERVER1 /* STM32WB - P2P Server 1*/,
    0x00 /* GROUP A Feature  */,
    0x0C /* GROUP A Feature */, // Enable Temperature bit18 and Humdity bit19
    0x00 /* GROUP B Feature */,
    0x00 /* GROUP B Feature */,
    0x00, /* BLE MAC start -MSB */
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00, /* BLE MAC stop */
};
#endif
```

Comment: Hey! Would you mind telling me how you got that ''C'? How does putting C there set both bit18 and bit19?

Comment: If you are using the ST BLE Sensor App this uses the BlueST protocol. see [BlueST Protocol](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/BlueSTSDK_Android) the bytes in the array are listed MSB to LSB. so 0x000C0000 = b'00000000 00001100 00000000 00000000.